# how to delete up extra line breakers in string

Tags: java, string, split, system.out

I have got a text like this in my String s (which I have already read from `txt.file`)

```
 trump;Donald Trump;trump@yahoo.eu    
 obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com   
 bush;George Bush;bush@inbox.com    
 clinton,Bill Clinton;clinton@mail.com
```

**Then I'm trying to cut off everything besides an e-mail address and print out on console**

```
String f1[] = null;
f1=s.split("(.*?);");
for (int i=0;i<f1.length;i++) {
       System.out.print(f1[i]);
   }
```

and I have output like this:

```
trump@yahoo.eu  
obama@google.com   
bush@inbox.com  
clinton@mail.com
```

How can I avoid such output, I mean how can I get output text without line breakers?

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: trump@yahoo.euobama@google.combush@inbox.comclinton@mail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below approach. I have read your file with `Scanner` as well as `BufferedReader` and in both cases, I don't get any line break. `file.txt` is the file that contains text and the logic of splitting remains the same as you did

```
public class CC {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String f1[] = null;
        f1 = scan.nextLine().split("(.*?);");
        for (int i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(f1[i]);
        }
    }
    scan.close();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
    String str = null;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String f1[] = null;
        f1 = str.split("(.*?);");
        for (int i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(f1[i]);
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just replace all line breakers as shown in the below code:

```
String f1[] = null;
f1=s.split("(.*?);");
for (int i=0;i<f1.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(f1[i].replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", ""));
}
```

This will replace all of them with no space.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "trump;Donald Trump;trump@yahoo.eu    "
                + "obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com   "
                + "bush;George Bush;bush@inbox.com    "
                + "clinton;Bill Clinton;clinton@mail.com";

        String spaceStrings[] = s.split("[\\s,;]+");
        String output="";
        for(String word:spaceStrings){
            if(validate(word)){
                output+=word;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = Pattern.compile(
            "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static boolean validate(String emailStr) {
        Matcher matcher = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX.matcher(emailStr);
        return matcher.find();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of split, you might match an email like format by matching not a semicolon or a whitespace character one or more times using a negated character class `[^\\s;]+` followed by an @ and again matching not a semicolon or a whitespace character.

```
final String regex = "[^\\s;]+@[^\\s;]+";
final String string = "trump;Donald Trump;trump@yahoo.eu    \n"
         + " obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com   \n"
         + " bush;George Bush;bush@inbox.com    \n"
         + " clinton,Bill Clinton;clinton@mail.com";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(String.join("", matches));
```

`[^\\s;]+@[^\\s;]+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZF6P9B/1)

[Java demo](http://rextester.com/TPAX56655)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace '\n' that may arrive at start and end.
write this way.

```
String f1[] = null;
f1=s.split("(.*?);");
for (int i=0;i<f1.length;i++) {
f1[i] = f1[i].replace("\n");
System.out.print(f1[i]);
}
```